# Makefile: target-specific variables are always resolved

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following `Makefile`:

```
foo: FOOVAR:=$(shell prog_to_execute_only_on_foo)
foo:
    echo "foo"

bar:
    echo "bar"
```

I would like to be able to run `make bar` without resolving the shell command for `FOOVAR`.

Is it possible?

If not, is there a way to work around this? to make sure the shell command will not be executed when running `make bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by defining `FOOVAR` as a [*recursively expanded variable*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html) instead of a *simply expanded variable* (i.e., by using `=` instead of `:=`):

```
foo: FOOVAR = $(shell prog_to_execute_only_on_foo)
foo:
    echo "foo"
```

This way `prog_to_execute_only_on_foo` will be executed when `FOOVAR` is expanded.

Note, however, that `prog_to_execute_only_on_foo` will be executed *every time* that `FOOVAR` is expanded, whereas for the *simply expanded variable* (i.e., `:=`) it will be only executed *once*.